# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ decomposable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have to find a ring with a module M and a submodule of M, N st. M is indecomposable and M/N is not, and got the idea to use $\mathbb{Z}$ as my ring and module, and $6\mathbb{Z}$ as my submodule. I know $\mathbb{Z}_6 = \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and thus is decomposable, but now i'm in doubt whether $\mathbb{Z}$ is.

Comment: It is not, as it would imply $\mathbf Z$ has nontrivial idempotents.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\mathbb{Z}=A\times B$, $A,B$ not trivial. we denote $p_A:A\times B\rightarrow A$ the projection, $B$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}/p_A(\mathbb{Z})$ and $A$ is isomorphic to$\mathbb{Z}/p_B(\mathbb{Z})$ which are finite implies that $\mathbb{Z}$ finite contradiction.